# how to get multiple records with same id if there is multiple <data> element in c# from xml

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I want multiple records if there is a multiple data element , so id and log element will be remain same for each data record.

note : there will be multiple  element in xml , below example , below is only for single

xml Code :

```
<pay>
  <id>1</id>
  <data>
    <startDate>2016-03-03</startDate>
    <adjustedDueDate>2016-03-31</adjustedDueDate>
    <Rate>50</Rate>
</data>
<data>
    <startDate>2016-04-04</startDate>
    <adjustedDueDate>2016-04-04</adjustedDueDate>
    <Rate>12</Rate>
</data>
<log>IMP</log>
</pay>
```

C# code

```
string path = @"E:\XMLFile1.xml";
XDocument xmlExeDoc = XDocument.Load(path);
var recordsFac = xmlExeDoc.Descendants("pay").Select(x => new
{
    id = (string)x.Element("id"),
    cycle = x.Elements("data").Select(y => new
    {
        startDate = (y.Elements("startDate").Any() == true) ? (string)y.Element("startDate") : string.Empty,
        adjustedDueDate = (DateTime)y.Element("adjustedDueDate"),
        Rate = (decimal)y.Element("Rate")
    }).Where(y => y.Rate > 0 && y.adjustedDueDate < DateTime.Now)
                           .Select
                           (
                               c => new
                               {
                                   startDate = c.startDate,
                                   adjustedDueDate = c.adjustedDueDate,
                                   Rate = c.Rate
                               }
                           ).FirstOrDefault(),

    log = x.Element("log")
}).ToList();
```

required output :

output:

### [0] {1,2016-03-03,2016-03-31,50,IMP}

### [1] {1,2016-04-04,2016-04-04,12,IMP}

### need same output like  here but another element  added i have coded like given below is it right way to do it , need 2 rows of  and 2 rows of  element.

```
<pay>
  <id>1</id>
  <data>
    <startDate>2016-03-03</startDate>
    <adjustedDueDate>2016-03-31</adjustedDueDate>
    <Rate>50</Rate>
</data>
<data>
    <startDate>2016-04-04</startDate>
    <adjustedDueDate>2016-04-04</adjustedDueDate>
    <Rate>12</Rate>
</data>
<log>IMP</log>
</pay>
<ClientData>
    <startDate>2016-07-04</startDate>
    <adjustedDueDate>2016-08-04</adjustedDueDate>
    <Rate>100</Rate>
</ClientData>
<ClientData>
    <startDate>2016-09-04</startDate>
    <adjustedDueDate>2016-09-04</adjustedDueDate>
    <Rate>555</Rate>
</ClientData>
</pay>



var recordsFac = xmlExeDoc.Descendants("pay").Select(x => new
{

    cycle = x.Elements("data").Select(y => new
    {
        id = (string)x.Element("id"),
        startDate = (y.Elements("startDate").Any() == true) ? (string)y.Element("startDate") : string.Empty,
        adjustedDueDate = (DateTime)y.Element("adjustedDueDate"),
        Rate = (decimal)y.Element("Rate"),
        log = x.Element("log")
    }).Where(y => y.Rate > 0 && y.adjustedDueDate < DateTime.Now),
    ClientData = x.Elements("data").Select(y => new
    {
        id = (string)x.Element("id"),
        startDate = (y.Elements("startDate").Any() == true) ? (string)y.Element("startDate") : string.Empty,
        adjustedDueDate = (DateTime)y.Element("adjustedDueDate"),
        Rate = (decimal)y.Element("Rate"),
        log = x.Element("log")
    }).Where(y => y.Rate > 0 && y.adjustedDueDate < DateTime.Now)

}).ToList();
```

is the above code is right way to achieve this :

output :

### [0] {1,2016-03-03,2016-03-31,50,IMP}

[1] {1,2016-04-04,2016-04-04,12,IMP}

### [2] {1,2016-07-04,2016-08-04,100,IMP}

[3] {1,2016-09-04,2016-09-04,555,IMP}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your queries are already producing what you're asking, but you're restricting the cycle query to FirstOrDefault, so it is only going to produce 1 record.  If you remove that then cycle contains both records.

To get the id and log in the same record as the dates, just include them in the final anonymous class you're creating :

```
var recordsFac = xmlExeDoc.Descendants("pay").Select(x => new
{

    cycle = x.Elements("data").Select(y => new
    {
        startDate = (y.Elements("startDate").Any() == true) ? (string)y.Element("startDate") : string.Empty,
        adjustedDueDate = (DateTime)y.Element("adjustedDueDate"),
        Rate = (decimal)y.Element("Rate"),
    }).Where(y => y.Rate > 0 && y.adjustedDueDate < DateTime.Now)
                           .Select
                           (
                               c => new
                               {
                                   id = (string)x.Element("id"),
                                   startDate = c.startDate,
                                   adjustedDueDate = c.adjustedDueDate,
                                   Rate = c.Rate,
                                   log = x.Element("log")
                               }
                           ),

}).ToList();
```

recordsFac will contain records for each pay element in the xml file. the cycle property for each record will contain the data as you've outlined.  A simple nested foreach loop will access the data:

```
foreach(var record in recordsFac)
{
    foreach(var record2 in record.cycle)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{record2.id},{record2.startDate},{record2.adjustedDueDate},{record2.log}");
    }
}
```

Just took another look at your code and noticed the last select is redundant and can be removed:

```
var recordsFac = xmlExeDoc.Descendants("pay").Select(x => new
{

    cycle = x.Elements("data").Select(y => new
    {
        id = (string)x.Element("id"),
        startDate = (y.Elements("startDate").Any() == true) ? (string)y.Element("startDate") : string.Empty,
        adjustedDueDate = (DateTime)y.Element("adjustedDueDate"),
        Rate = (decimal)y.Element("Rate"),
        log = x.Element("log")
    }).Where(y => y.Rate > 0 && y.adjustedDueDate < DateTime.Now)               
}).ToList();

foreach(var record in recordsFac)
{
    foreach(var record2 in record.cycle)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{record2.id},{record2.startDate},{record2.adjustedDueDate},{record2.log}");
    }
}
```

Comment: but how can i get this records list if there are multiple <Pay> element in xml

Comment: what if data element missing

Comment: @yashfale - I added more examples for you.  Any missing element won't create a record.